# What if sentence begins with a verb in second form?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, conditional-constructions, translation

I'm trying to translate the answer I've received on the other StackExchnage's site: https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/42539/22065

Here's the sentence:

> **Provided you match the field of view** (by multiplying the focal length by 1.6) and keep the entrance pupil diameter the same (by multiplying the f-number by 1.6) then form a purely theoretical point of view depth of field and the amount of background blur will be the same.

A classic sentence in English is often SOV (subject + object + verb) or SVO (subject + verb + object).

In the sentence I've quoted above, the sentence begins with the verb (or not the verb?) that has the 2nd (or 3rd) form. Then comes the subject and then the object etc.

So, how should I translate the beginning part of this sentence? How this form is named? Where I can read about it?

Comment: Translate the '*Provided [that] you*' as '*As long as you*'- it's a constraint.  He is saying that the result he quotes is valid only when 'you match the field of view ...'

Comment: @Jim does it mean that I should just remember that?

Comment: Note that *form* should be *from*. The first clause of the sentence stops before *then*. I've [proposed](http://photo.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/11549) an edit to that answer which should make it a little easier to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[Provided (that)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/provided9)" ("that" [can be omitted](http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/provided_providing.htm)) is a [conjunction](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/provided) that means "under the condition that". A conjunction is a word with the purpose of connecting phrases.